# how to get doctype tag with url using xsl:output

Tags: html, xslt, internet-explorer, dtd, doctype

i have added the below xsl:output tag in xslt

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" ></xsl:output>

as a result i get the below doctype tag in the html output-

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

how can i mention the url in the doctype tag using xsl:output which would output a doctype tag that looks like below

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "_http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Best Regards, 
 Keshav

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick trip to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_output.asp) reveals that the XSL:Output element has a **doctype-system** attribute available, as well as a **doctype-public**. I believe this is what you need.

If you change your xsl:output to the following

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="_http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" ></xsl:output>
```

You should get the DTD output you require, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "_http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```